# Access a chart in a different function

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I am rendering charts using chart.js

Is it possible to access a chart in a different function through the canvas object? I want to update it if a certain button is clicked.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a chart initialized like so

```
var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data);
```

myNewChart.chart.canvas is your canvas object. Note that you'll have to handle the redraws that happen for tooltip display / removal, animation (initial draw, if enabled) and chart resizes.

While you can also access the canvas using `document.getElementById("myId")` and the context using `document.getElementById("myId").getContext("2d")`, you won't have access to the chart functions like .update(), .addData(), etc.. For this you need the chart instance.

Since every available chart instance is also stored in Chart.instances (and since Chart is global), you could do something like so

```
for (instance in Chart.instances) { 
    if (Chart.instances[instance].chart.canvas === document.getElementById("myId")) {
        console.log("found my chart instance")
        console.log(Chart.instances[instance])
    }
}
```

to get the chart instance.

Comment: but i can't access the var myNewChart if its in a different function because its not a global variable. so i was wondering if you could access it through document.getElementById("chart"), which is the canvas object

Comment: Oh yes, it's the same canvas object, you can access it that way too. You need to get the context if you want to draw though - document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d")

Comment: right so is it possible to access the chart through that canvas? like instead of redrawing it, updating it or access its data? in other words could you do something like document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d").update

Comment: No problem. Your comments were clear enough. Cheers!